# Hide on screen buttons in android phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, fullscreen

I've made an app for Android using phonegap and i wanted to make it really full screen and hide/remove the buttons at the bottom of the screen (The back button, the home button and the app switcher button) I know this is possible because the BBC iPlayer app does it when you're viewing a video, but i dont know if it's possible with phonegap, Does anyone know if it is, and if so, could you point me in the right direction

Comment: What would you like me to show? I don't think there's anything i could show you that would help this, I have no idea if this is even possible so i haven't started, I just want a pointer in the right direction, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible - I haven't used the BBC Sport app properly, but hazard a guess it uses the device's default player (which is an Android player) and thus this is the only desirable time you want full-screen mode.

Android relies on those buttons - otherwise, how can you exit the app? It's like the home button on iOS - you need it to operate the device.

There *are* event listeners you can use for the back button and menu button which you can override the default behaviour for:

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function () {
    // do something when back is pressed
}, false);

document.addEventListener('menubutton', function () {
    // do something when menu is pressed
}, false);
```

That's about it though. Think in terms of the Samsung Galaxy phones - these are hard buttons and so you can't 'hide' them like you can on stock Android.

Comment: This isn't true anymore. Android apps CAN hide the software control buttons. The user swipes down from the top of the screen to reveal the OS controls. It would be useful to update this answer with how to control this in Cordova.