# Hiding Home and Back button in Android

Tags: android, back-button, android-homebutton

I would like my app to hide the Home and Back button which is show at bottom of activity.

I was able to hide the title bar but I am not able to do for Home and Back button.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not: see my related answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574530/hide-on-screen-buttons-in-android-phonegap-app/21577505?noredirect=1#comment32597476_21577505

Comment: But I have seen some apps where the Home and Back buttons are hidden but on clicking on the activity it appears back. How is that?

Comment: @2Dee thanks :) it worked. I did search but dint come across that post. Anyways thanks :) For others who are searching how to do it here it is: myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Starting from Android 4.4 KitKat, you can use "immersive" full-screen mode. Here's the detail and some sample codes.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: I had already got my ans but I will mark this as ans since it also answers my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Droider what did u do?to support it in the versions before kitkat?

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

Comment: you saved me .thanks